# ASP.NET div tag fit

Tags: html, asp.net, css, resize

My problem is the following.

I'd like to automatically resize my `<div>` tag, but it always fit just the current window and not all of my `body` tag.

I foun so many solution but nothing helps me a lot. So if you have any idea please share with me.

I attached a PrintScreen, my CSS and HTML code snippet.

Tank you!

[image]

```css
.Body
{
    background-color:white; 
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px; 
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.Fejlec_Div 
{
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#C0C0C0); 
}


.Fejlec_label
{
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:xx-large;
}

.Fejlec_label_Div
{
    width:600px;
}

.Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_elso_cella 
{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_masodik_cella
{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_harmadik_cella 
{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_negyedik_cella 
{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="nissin_1.master.cs" Inherits="nissin_net.nissin_1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" runat="server">
    <head id="Master_Head" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head_Contentplaceholder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <title id="Master_Title" runat="server"></title>
    </head>
    <body id="Body" runat="server" class="Body">
        <link id="Css_Link" runat="server" href="Master_design.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link id="Shortcur_icon_Link" runat="server" href="~/Resources/nissin_logo.png" rel="icon"/>
        <form id="Master_Form" runat="server">
            <div id="Fejlec_Div" runat="server" class="Fejlec_Div">
                <asp:table ID="Fejlec_Table" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor" runat="server" CssClass="Fejlec_Table">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_elso_cella" runat="server" CssClass="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_elso_cella">
                            <asp:Image ID="Fejlec_logo_Image" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/nissin_logo.png"/> 
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell id="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_masodik_cella" runat="server" CssClass="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_masodik_cella" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <div id="Fejlec_label_Div" runat="server" class="Fejlec_label_Div">
                                <asp:Label CssClass="Fejlec_label" ID="Fejlec_Label" runat="server" Text="A Nissin Foods Kft. belső hálózata"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID = "Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_harmadik_cella" runat="server" CssClass="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_harmadik_cella">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Bejelentkezes_Contentplaceholder" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_negyedik_cella" runat="server" CssClass="Fejlec_tabla_elso_sor_negyedik_cella">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Nyelvek_Contentplaceholder" runat ="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                         
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:table>  
            </div>          
            <div id="Kozep_Div" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Kozep_Contentplaceholder" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML rather than your .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because your body width is 100%. It means, that your body element will be fit according to your browser window width. You should specify your body width in px instead of percents. For example:

```
.Body {
    ...
    width: 1200px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Does it mean, I can get always the current size of my browser and fit my `body` tag to them?

Comment: @Gabor, In this case - yes, but this is not a good way. You should build your html code more responsive to users, since all of them probably might have different screen resolution, that affects to width of their browser's window. You may get acquainted with responsive design more detail using google search.